# Do the Swedish police have a special code for immigrant crimes?

Tags: law-enforcement, immigration, sweden

An article I read today asserts the Swedish police have a special 'code 291' for crimes committed by muslim immigrants. This code would be used to 'bury' crimes such as sexual assault by refugees. A total of +/- 5000 crimes are supposed to have been filed under this code.

Most websites talking about this seem to have a partisan slant, except the initial article I read (Dutch):

[Europa, leg je sluier af](http://www.standaard.be/cnt/dmf20170223_02746590) (De Standaard, 23 feb 2017)

[Swedish police was forced to conceal 5,000 Muslim crimes in four months under ‘Refugee Code 291’](https://themuslimissue.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/swedish-police-was-forced-to-conceal-5000-muslim-crimes-in-four-months-under-refugee-code-291/) (The Muslim Issue, 11 Feb 2017)

[Second Swedish Police Officer Blows the Whistle on Migrant Crime Cover-Up](http://www.infowars.com/second-swedish-police-officer-blows-the-whistle-on-migrant-crime-cover-up/) (InfoWars, 7 feb 2017)

What proof is there that:

- this code exists?
- it is used to hide crimes by muslim refugees from the media/public?
- finally what kind of crimes would have been hidden?

Comment: That first article requires registration. Due to current large scale internet issues in The Netherlands I was unable to complete that registration. I wanted to quote and translate the article. Menno, please do that a.s.a.p., you should have done that in the first place.

Comment: relevant and recent: http://www.government.se/articles/2017/02/facts-about-migration-and-crime-in-sweden/

Comment: On the third link, the police officer in question was one that ranted on a blog by stating the first name of all the people he had had dealings with during a shift. Since he was working in a neighbourhood that had a high density of first or second generation new swedes, naturally it filled up with foreign sounding names. A colleague of his, who got tired of the publicity this guy got did the same thing, but he worked in an area where primarily old swedes lived. You can guess the result. That didn't stop the xenophobes from hailing the first guy as a hero though, while hushing up the colleague.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors could you provide a source for this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

That there is a police code is true. The Swedish police use different codes for different types of work as a way to track, for instance, how much resources they use. Some examples of such police codes are 204 (biker gangs), 209 (animal rights activist) and 207 (Satanist).[Poliskoder](http://www.polisradio.net/poliskoder.htm)

Issues related to asylum accommodations are coded as 291. So it's not about Muslims. It don't actually even have to be about refugees. For instance, if someone tries to burn down an asylum accommodation it would also be a 291. It's also not only about crimes, but also attempted suicides, missing persons and so on.

As opposed to the reports, it is not used to keep anything secret. For instance, you can tell that it was used for 559 registered assaults, 450 fights, 194 cases of violent threats, 58 fires, 2 bomb threats, 9 robberies, 4 rapes, 37 cases of attempted suicide, 42 cases of people reported as "mentally ill",  96 missing persons, and 3 deaths. [The Local](http://www.thelocal.se/20160129/swedish-police-files-5000-migrant-incidents-sin)

It's not 5000+ crimes, but they count each event: 912 cases where refugees were sheltered from (real or suspected) far-right attacks, 26 cases of someone being ill, 239 cases where an automatic alarm went off, 869 cases for checking vehicles or persons were counted. [Vad är egentligen kod 291](http://polimasaren.se/vad-ar-egentligen-kod-291/) In total it was used for 3287 events, or about one percent of the police work.[Bearbetning av händelserapporter och brottsanmälningar, Alma](https://polisen.se/PageFiles/615116/Antal_handelserapporter_och_brottsanmalningar.pdf)

Comment: And of course, the real question is not how many crimes were reported under this code, but rather how many were reported relative to the population size.

Comment: @nbubis The Swedish population is very close to 10 million people. Statistics Sweden puts the population as of December 2016 at 9,995,153. http://www.scb.se/en/finding-statistics/statistics-by-subject-area/population/population-composition/population-statistics/

Comment: For what it's worth, I would not consider either of the cited sources trustworthy in and of themselves. They may be *correct*, but for *trustworthy* I'd want something that I have at least heard of before, and/or where there is clear information about who is the publisher of the information. The second link in particular appears to be someone's private blog; I thought the standards for source material on [skeptics.se] were a little higher than that.

Comment: It would seem that coding police responses under this code would do the opposite from burying them. The code is the reason we know about the 559 assaults as a distinct category, as separated from all the assaults that have happened anywhere in Sweden. If you actually wanted to bury these cases, you would presumably want to mix them in with everything else, not go out of your way to classify them.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling [The Local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Local) has only been around since 2004, and is in English. I can't say why you haven't heard of it; even in the USA I am familiar with it!

Comment: Might be better to directly source those numbers from whatever agency tracks those things in Sweden. I've never heard of "The Local" but even highly respectable news media can get things wrong.

Comment: @ventsyv Ok, I've added a source directly from the Swedish police, but it requires that you understand Swedish.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Just a note: we have passed 10 million now. Citizen #10 000 000 received a letter written by the head of state. It was sometime after new years I think.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. The refugee debate is complex enough without arguing from semi-facts and distortions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code exists, and yes, police have been been using this code to hide the criminality of certain groups. Note that the code was for incidents related to the recent wave of asylum seekers (most of whom were Muslim), not for crimes committed by Muslims or immigrants as such.

Here's from one of Sweden's major regime-friendly media outlets:

> Polisen vägrar berätta hur stora resurser som går åt till att hantera flyktingvågen och den alltmer spända situationen på många asylboenden. Utredningar om våld, hot och andra brott kodas med siffran ”291” och hemlighålls för massmedia.
>
> ”Ingenting ska ut”, står det i ett internt direktiv som DN läst.

My translation:

> The police refuse to say how great the resources are that are spent on handling the wave of refugees and the increasingly tense situation at many refugee shelters. Investigations of violence, threats, and other crimes are coded with the number ”291” and kept secret from the mass media.
>
> ”Nothing must come out”, says an internal directive read by DN.

http://www.dn.se/nyheter/sverige/polisen-hemlighaller-fakta-om-sitt-flyktingarbete/

There was some criticism in the comments about the motive behind this coverup not being clear. These two articles should clarify things for those not familiar with Swedish political reality.
Here is from an article about the coverup by the Police of gang sexual assaults at a music festival:

> Flera av de poliser som DN pratat med menar att myndigheten medvetet undviker att rapportera om fenomenen som knyts till gärningsmän med utländsk bakgrund.

[...]

> – Det här är en öm punkt, vi vågar ibland inte säga som det är för att vi tror att det spelar Sverigedemokraterna i händerna. Vi får ta på oss det här inom polisen, säger polischefen Peter Ågren.

My translation:

> Several of the police officers DN has spoken to say that the Police consciously avoids reporting on phenomena associated with perpetrators with a foreign background.

[...]

> – This is a sensitive area, we sometimes don't dare to tell the truth because we think it will benefit Sverigedemokraterna*. We'll have to take responsibility for this in the Police, says Police Chief Peter Ågren.

- The only party in Parliament that opposed the liberal immigration policy at the time.

http://www.dn.se/nyheter/sverige/overgreppen-pa-festivalen-i-stockholm-rapporterades-aldrig-vidare/

In an article about the Police no longer giving out physical descriptions of perpetrators/suspects in another major regime-friendly newspaper, the Police PR officer says this:

> Vi vill undvika att peka ut etniska grupper som kriminella.

My translation:

> We wish to avoid identifying ethnic groups as criminal.

https://www.svd.se/internt-polisbrev-stoppar-signalement

Comment: What do you mean by *regime-friendly* in this context?  DN are a conservative newspaper and the government is social-democrat.

Comment: "and yes, police have been been using this code to hide the criminality of certain groups."

Your specific evidence that such a conspiracy is in progress is...what exactly?

Comment: Note also that referring to a government as a "regime" is, in general, not a neutral statement.

Comment: @gerrit DN is a liberal newspaper with liberal views on immigration. Swedish immigration policy has long been set by broad coalitions of immigration-liberal parties rather than by the government alone.

Comment: @zugzwang We need to be careful with terminology here.  In the USA, liberal means left-wing.  In Sweden, liberal typically means right-wing (pro-business, small government).  The Swedish government is not liberal but social-democratic.  There are social-democratic newspapers in Sweden, such as *Aftonbladet*, but *Dagens Nyheter* typically sides with Alliansen, the right-wing parties currently in opposition.

Comment: @DanHaynes I think the fact of the coverup is made clear in my original source. I've added two more sources to establish motive.

Comment: You do not address the issue of the codes also being used on reports of violence *against* recent immigrants. "Investigations of violence and threats" could easily be about violence perpetrated on, not by, immigrants.

Comment: @gerrit We're not talking about the US, so there's no reason to involve US definitions. And I don't think there's any country in which DN wouldn't qualify as liberal on immigration. In a multi-party parliamentary democracy such as Sweden, different parties can be in opposition on different issues, and neither the Alliansen parties nor DN is in opposition on immigration policy, which is what's relevant here. See e.g. https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migrationsöverenskommelsen

Comment: @DJClayworth http://www.dn.se/nyheter/sverige/polisen-slapper-asylbrottssiffror/ says that 2368 out of the 3287 code-291 crimes that were reported had asylum seekers as suspects, i.e. 72 %.

Comment: You would have to substantiate how keeping stats classified for the duration of a project could be considered a cover up when the numbers were put out in a report literally the very same day the project wrapped up.
Pro tip #2: calling a democracy's largest broadsheet a "regime-friendly media outlet" instantly outs you as a loon. As such it's very, very important that you keep doing so.